# jQuery search each table row for a particular td

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider there's a table with rows to which a `td` with class `x` is added by jQuery on the fly (during DOM manipulation). Later when the user submit's this table (table being part of a form), i want to search all the rows for existence of this particular `td`. If this `td` is found then the function should return false, else true. However this piece of code does not work, any suggestions?

```
function validate(){
$('form#newuser table tr').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('td.x')){
        return false;
    }
});
return true;
}
```

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that `.find()` always returns an object, even if it is empty.  But there's no need for the each either.  (not going to post an answer since the answer there is a good one, just wanted to explain why).

Comment: TY for the precision, this bothered me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function validate() { 
  return ($('form#newuser table tr td.x').length == 0);
};
```

`$(<selector>).length` returns the number of DOM elements matched by the `<selector>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can forget the each loop, too and really shorten this up since your selector will find ALL tr's (it's a set)...

```
function validate(){
   if($('form#newuser table tr.x').length){
     return false;
   }

});
return true;
}
```

i havent tested this, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
$('#YourFormName TABLE TBODY TR').each(function()
{        
 if $(this).children('td').hasClass('x')
   {
     return false;
   }
});
```